# Deleting Windows after Installing Ubuntu

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, windows

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop using the Windows Interface installer and it works just fine but now I want to get rid of Windows 7 permanently because it is simply a burden and uses up 50GB of disk space and is virtually usless to me now. 
Since this type of installation uses Windows as the "host" OS  if there is any problem with windows in the future I'm afraid that may compromise the functioning of Ubuntu.
Is it possible to do this while Ubuntu is still on my primary drive? 
I have all my data backed up on Drive D:\
So can I format only that part of C:\ that has Windows on it leaving Ubuntu intact or do I have to format the entire C:\ drive?

Comment: No, you can not. It's not possible to format parts of a partition, and yes, it will also break the Ubuntu installation.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends where have you installed GRUB, in MBR or on Windows partition.

If it is in MBR, there is no need to boot Windows anymore, and if you want to make use of that partition, just open fdisk (or parted), change type of partion from NTFS to Linux and start mkfs.ext3 or mkfs.ext4 to make Linux partition on former Windows partition.

If GRUB is on start of Windows partition, move it to MBR, and follow above procedure.

There are no examples of commands above as above there is no exact data about disk/partitions used (/dev/sda or /dev/sdb, sda1, sda2, sda3 etc). If you need exact commands, please give us more detailed description of your system.